# Android Studio Freezing

Tags: android-studio

I have recently started programming on Android Studio on my Macbook Air 2019. Android Studio itself works completely fine but when I try to create a new virtual device Android Studio freezes. Does anyone know why or how I can get past this.

Comment: check your task manager processes

Comment: Is there something specific that should not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I needed to change the open documents in new tab to never in system preferences. The issue is a bug with android studio on MacOS Big Sur.